# Twitter 401 error when using nltk.twitter

Tags: twitter

I am trying to get tweets from twitter with the following code:

```
import nltk


from nltk.twitter import Twitter
    tw = Twitter()
    tw.tweets(keywords='love, hate', limit=10)
```

I am getting a 401 error. My credentials are in a credentials.txt file. They work with tweepy but not with nltk. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `nltk.twitter` requires your credentials.txt file path in TWITTER environment variable and the data inside the text file has to be entered correctly.

For example:

```
app_key=YOUR CONSUMER KEY  
app_secret=YOUR CONSUMER SECRET  
oauth_token=YOUR ACCESS TOKEN  
oauth_token_secret=YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
```

There should be no space before of after the '='. Also, don't put the key in quotes like "YOUR CONSUMER KEY".

This solved my issue with `401`.